# Customizing bibliography styles

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, natbib

I cite two papers and want to change style of bibliography, that is changing style of one and keep another unchanged.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}

\begin{document}

 My citation \citep{desmet2015geography}

 another citation \citep{roberts2012evaluating}

\medskip
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{citation}

\end{document}
```

Bibliography file (citation.bib)

```
@article{roberts2012evaluating,
Author = {Roberts, Mark and Deichmann, Uwe and Fingleton, Bernard and Shi, Tuo},
Journal = {Regional Science and Urban Economics},
Number = {4},
Pages = {580--594},
Publisher = {Elsevier},
Title = {Evaluating China's road to prosperity: A new economic geography approach},
Volume = {42},
Year = {2012}}

@techreport{desmet2015geography,
Author = {Desmet, Klaus and Nagy, D{\'a}vid Kriszti{\'a}n and Rossi-Hansberg, Esteban},
Date-Added = {2016-09-03 13:29:14 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2016-09-03 13:29:14 +0000},
Institution = {National Bureau of Economic Research},
Title = {The geography of development: Evaluating migration restrictions and coastal flooding},
Year = {2015}}
```

IDE:Texpad 1.731

Engine: Xelatex, BibTex

Compiled output of the mini example:
[image]
Desired output:
[image]

Comment: If I interpret your write-up correctly, you want `&` (ampersand) to be the connector in some cases but not in others. Which criterion drives the selection? (I assume the bibliography contains more than two entries...)

Comment: @Mico I hope use similar command (\citep) to specific the one need to change. And in this case is the second one.

Comment: You appear to use `\citep` to cite both entries: How are LaTeX and BibTeX to know which formatting rule applies to which case? As you probably know, `\citep` affects the way the citation call-out is formed, *not* the way the bibliographic entry is formatted; after all, one and the same bibliographic entry can be referenced via `\citet`, `\citep`, etc. Incidentally, what is the use case for wanting to use two different conjunctions (`and` and `&`) for one and the same job -- formatting lists of authors.

Comment: @Mico Can I define a new command to execute this change? Such as difine  \citep_p for \citep,  \cite_e for \cite. I don't know whether it works. I'm quite new to Latex and hope you can help me. Thanks!

Comment: I must confess I don't understand how you are going to inform LaTeX and BibTeX about the choice of conjunction particle (`and` and `&`).  How are `\cite_e` and `\cite_p` supposed to differ? I also don't understand *why* you would want to use two different conjunction particles in the first place.

Comment: @ Mico Or can I edit the bibliography file to specific the one need to change?

Comment: I've edited your posting to add the 'biblatex' tag. It's possible that your formatting objective can be handled with `biblatex` and `biber`, as they are far more powerful and customizable than BibTeX is. Hopefully, some of the biblatex experts who frequent this site can offer an answer.

Comment: You can cheat and get your output with this author declaration: `Author = {Roberts, Mark and Deichmann, Uwe and {Bernard Fingleton \& Tuo Shi}},`. But it is a quite bad hack and so indicates that something is very wrong with your style. Such inconsistent formatting looks very unprofessional.

Comment: Off-topic: In the entry with key `roberts2012evaluating`, in the `title` field, you should encase the word `China` in curly braces to prevent BibTeX from changing it to lower-case mode. (You would agree that "... china's road to ..." isn't correct, right?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only information that is shuttled between LaTeX and BibTeX is the cite key. So if you want to distinguish between entries that should use "and" an ones that should use "&" then it seems you should pass this information with the cite key. So here is my solution that does that.

1. The entries that should use "&" will get a cite key that ends in "&". In the above example this is in the bibliography file:

   ```
   @article{roberts2012evaluating&,
   Author = {Roberts, Mark and Deichmann, Uwe and Fingleton, Bernard and Shi, Tuo},
   Journal = {Regional Science and Urban Economics},
   Number = 4,
   Pages = {580--594},
   Publisher = {Elsevier},
   Title = {Evaluating {China}'s road to prosperity: A new economic geography approach},
   Volume = 42,
   Year = 2012}
   ```

and the citation command becomes

```
\citep{roberts2012evaluating&}
```

(Interestingly, a bare `&` is allowed.)

2. Now we have to change the bibliography style to generate a macro `\AND` instead of "and". So we make a copy of `plainnat.bst` and call it `myplainnat.bst`. The differences are (replace the first line by the second one.):

l. 232 and 325

```
       { " and " * t * }
       { " \AND{} " * t * }
```

l. 1111

```
    { " and " * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }
    { " \AND{} " * s #2 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$ * }
```

3. Now use `\bibliographystyle{myplainnat}` instead of the `plainnat` one.
   And we have to rewrite `\bibitem` to check if the cite key ends with `&` and then define `\AND` as `&` if so, and as `and` otherwise.

So here is the adapted MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand\AND{and}
\let\origbibitem\bibitem
\renewcommand\bibitem[2][]{%
   \bibitemcheckkey{#2}\origbibitem[#1]{#2}}
\newcommand\bibitemcheckkey[1]{%
    \bibitemampcheck#1&\relax}
\def\bibitemampcheck#1&#2\relax{%
     \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{&}}{\def\AND{\&}}{\def\AND{and}}}

\begin{document}

 My citation \citep{desmet2015geography}

 another citation \citep{roberts2012evaluating&}

\medskip
\bibliographystyle{myplainnat}
\bibliography{citation}

\end{document}
```